# Switching back to master branch to work in isolated env

Tags: git

I'm in `master` branch.

1. `git checout -b new-branch`
2. `mkdir new-branch-stuff`
3. `cd new-branch-stuff`
4. `echo "new stuff here" >> stuff.txt`
5. `git add stuff.txt`

Then at this point I decide that I have to work on something else (since my boss asked me to work on something urgent). So I'm going to switch back on `master` branch

1. `checkout master`
2. `git status`

I can see this, which is from my new-branch where I've supposed to switch from

> ```
> % git checkout master
> A    ..new-branch-stuff/stuff.txt
> ```

What I expect **is not to see my old branch-specific files**. Because I want be in master isolated environment to be save knowing what I'm about to change on that current branch.

**Q:** What is the way git would suggest to go about this?

(I'm kind of new in git.. still. Trying to get my head around proper working with branches)

Comment: If you just want to stash your changes for later try `git stash` before checking out master.

Comment: I thought switching is about that - shows only that content where I switched to.

Comment: Thankfully, no that is not the case. I say thankfully because i tend to get bright ideas, start hammering away at some code, realize its going to take more then i expect and that i should create a new branch. So i create a branch, check it out and my half done work comes with me.

Comment: As @Victory notes, git's philosophy (as it were) is to let you arrange your stage however you like, and then suddenly realize: oh gosh I should put this on a different branch, so do the `git checkout -b` after the stage is set, and only then commit.  So changes follow you around as you change branches, until committed (then they stop following-around).  (I do the same thing a lot ... start on something thinking it's trivial, realize it's a lot more work than I expected, etc.)

Comment: Until you `commit` your changes, they are still just loose files laying around, not part of the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not yet done a `git commit`.

The `git checkout -b` created the new branch and put you on it.  But that's all it did.

Any time you do a `git add`, changes you have become staged to go into the next commit.  (Changes you have that have not been `git add`ed are not-yet-staged.)  But in any case, you have not made a commit.

Then, you said `git checkout master`.  Git made sure that switching from branch `new-branch` to `master` would not lose anything (it won't, in this case) so it switched from branch `new-branch` back to `master`.

The change you staged, `git add stuff.txt`, is still staged for the next commit.  You haven't made a commit yet, so it comes with you into branch `master`.

If you wish to save it away on the new branch, first switch back, then commit:

- use `git checkout new-branch` to get back to `new-branch`
- at any time, use `git status` and/or `git diff --cached` to see what you will commit
- at any time, use `git diff` to see what you *won't* commit
- at any time, use `git commit` to commit it, on whatever branch you are on right then.